# Return from map after filter better way

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-stream

hello I have this function setanimalhappy to my Zoo program,
but I don't think it's well written  i think  the code after return is addition, it is useless

`(return personRepository.save(person).getRecordList().parallelStream() .filter(record1 -> record1.getId().equals(animalRecord.getId())) .findFirst().orElseThrow(RecordException::new); }) .orElseThrow(PersonException::new);)`

get person ->  find record in record list -> update value save to record list  -> return edited record

how can i return record1 from map to outside function or make this code better ?

```
@PutMapping("/{id}/animalhappy")
@ResponseBody
public Record SetAnimalHappy(@PathVariable String id, @RequestBody Record animalRecord) {

    return personRepository.findById(id)
            .map(person -> {
                person.getRecordList().parallelStream()
                        .filter(record1 -> record1.getId().equals(animalRecord.getId()))
                        .findFirst()
                        .map(record1 -> {
                            record1.getAnimalStatus().setHappy(true);
                                    return record1;
                                }
                        ).orElseThrow(RecordException::new);

                personRepository.save(person);

                return personRepository.save(person).getRecordList().parallelStream()
                        .filter(record1 -> record1.getId().equals(animalRecord.getId()))
                        .findFirst().orElseThrow(RecordException::new);
            })
            .orElseThrow(PersonException::new);
}
```

Comment: `CrudRepository::findById` returns an `Optional` which might be empty and hence it would lead to `PersonException`. I think this is technically correct.

Comment: Just a note: Rename `Record` to something specific because java 14 introduced records and `Record` is a superclass of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't seem to need to `#map` here, as if the `Optional`s are empty, you want exceptions to be thrown:

```java
// this should probably live in the service layer instead of the controller layer:
public Record setAnimalHappy(String id, Record animalRecord) {
    Person person = personRepository
        .findById(id)
        .orElseThrow(PersonException::new);
    // the following might be replaced by recordService.findById(animalRecord.getId()),
    // while making sure the returned record belongs to `person`:
    Record record = person
        .getRecordList()
        .stream() // don't use parallel streams (unless you know what you're doing)
        .filter(record -> record.getId().equals(animalRecord.getId()))
        .findFirst()
        .orElseThrow(RecordException::new);
    // not 100% sure the 2 following lines behave the way you'd expect:
    record.getAnimalStatus().setHappy(true);
    personRepository.save(person);
    return record;
}
```

Business logic apart, something along those lines might be arguably more readable.

It's easy to lose yourself into callbacks when entering the functional programing world. One rule I tend to follow, is *"don't use `-> {`"* (multiline lambda expressions): either reorganise your code (like the above example), or use additional functions to improve readability.

Interesting related read: https://dzone.com/articles/functional-programming-patterns-with-java-8.

Comment: Not sure if OP knows what he is doing. The answer is clearly more readable but `CrudRepository::save` might contain some business logic or transformation on `Record`(maybe in the future). `CrudRepository::save` returns an updated entity so I think fetching the updated record and sending it back to the client would make much sense to avoid any future mishaps.

Comment: Most of the code should be in the service layer but unfortunately, it is in the controller.

Comment: @AniketSahrawat yeah exactly, I agree, hence my comment in the code. I didn't want to go too deep into this as the question was more about readability (if I understood it correctly). But updating `record` while saving `person` looks a bit dodgy indeed.

Comment: I added this (get person ->  find record in record list -> update value save to record list  -> return edited record)  for better understanding, im new with OOP and i learning if you have better way to write code so I would appreciate it